# Angular how to get height of dynamically created div and send it to sibling component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I have one `parent` and `2 child components` like below

**Parent-component.html**

```
<child-component-1 [id]="id"></child-component-1>
<child-component-2></child-component-2>
```

`child-component-1` has ngb-carousel component to show warnings and alerts to user.And this component is being created due to `id` and its `result` comes from `API` like below

**child-component-1.ts**

```
alertFound;

this.service.checkAlert(id).subscribe((result:any)=>{
 if(result.alertFound){
 this.alertFound=true;
}
})
```

**child-component-1.html**

```
<ngb-carousel #carousel *ngIf="alertFound" class="carousel-alert" [interval]="false" [wrap]="false"
  [showNavigationIndicators]="false">
........................(Things go on here after result comes)
</ngb-carousel>
```

In `child-component-2`,I need to get the `height` of this `ngb-alert` to make dynamic height calculation on the screen.If it exists,I need to subtract it from `window.innerheight`.

**child-component-2.html**

```
<div [style.height.px]="actualHeight"></div>
```

**child-component-2.ts**

```
this.actualHeight = window.innerHeight - 269;
```

Interestingly on `child-component-1` when I tried to track it like below

```
@ViewChild('carousel', {read: ElementRef, static:false}) elementView: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(){
  console.log(this.elementView.nativeElement.offSetHeight);
  //throws height of created carousel first,then if next id doesnt have alert still shows me the height which previously created
}
```

it shows previously created `carousel` height even though result is `false` and `carousel` couldn't be created at that moment.I guess this happening because result sometimes arrives very late,sometimes fast.To listen detections on `viewchild` I found something like below which works exactly as I wanted and solved emitting non-created alert height problem

```
  @ViewChildren('carousel', {read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainerRefs;

      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.viewContainerRefs.changes.subscribe(item => {
          if (item) {
             console.log(item._results[0]._lContainer[0][0].offsetHeight);
          }
        })
      }
```

Now problem is sending this height to child-component-2 where I should calculate height dynamically.

I considered 2 options.First one is creating subject on a service,emitting height to it from `child-component-1` and listening it on `child-component-2` like below

**service.ts**

```
  alertActive = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  setAlertHeight(value:number){
    this.alertActive.next(value)
  }
```

**child-component-1**

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.viewContainerRefs.changes.subscribe(item => {
      if (item) {
       this.service.setAlertHeight(item._results[0]._lContainer[0][0].offsetHeight);
      }
    })
  }
```

**child-component-2**

```
this.alertActive.subscribe(value=>{
 if(value){
   this.actualHeight-=value;
  }
})
```

On the example above,it causes the problem to bring height,even though alert not created.I logged subscribes on console from `child-2` and `child-1` and noticed that `child-2` prints to console even though child1 didnt emit anything to it.

So I considered another option to send height from child-1 to parent via @Output and then via Input to
child2 like below

**child-1**

```
  @Output() transferHeight: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  this.viewContainerRefs.changes.subscribe(item => {
      if (item) {
      this.transferHeight.emit(item._results[0]._lContainer[0][0].offsetHeight);
      }
    })
```

**parent**

```
    <child-component-1 (transferHeight)="transferedHeight($event)" [id]="id"></child-component-1>
    <child-component-2  [transferredHeight]="transferredHeight"></child-component-2>
 alertHeight;
 transferedHeight(comingHeight){
    this.alertHeight=comingHeight;
  }
```

**child-2**

```
  @Input() transferredHeight;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.actualHeight-=this.transferredHeight;
   }
```

this one really handles the problem that I mentioned previously.But if carousel created after child-2 created due to late network resut ,it returns undefined.Therefore I tried to use ngOnChanges to listen changes on the Input variable like below

```
   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes.transferredHeight.currentValue)
}
```

this console.log doesnt print anything although I implemented onChanges.So Im waiting for your help.If there's a way to listen `viewContainerRefs.changes` of child-1 from child-2 would be the best case

Comment: I had this kinda problem some weeks ago.Using jQuery also caused showing previously created div element.Im also curious how viewContainerRefs can be subscribed from other component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this attempt:

```js
alertActive = new BehaviorSubject(0);
setAlertHeight(value:number){
  this.alertActive.next(value)
}
```

triggered the height to be set even when the alert was not active was because you used a `BehaviorSubject` rather than just a `Subject`. A [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) provides an initial value (`0` in your case), so immediately upon subscription the subscriber will receive that initial value (or the latest emitted value).

So you were on the right track, you just needed to use a regular `Subject` instead because then subscribers won't receive any values until the `Subject` emits.

So your service could look like this:

```js
private _alertActive = new Subject<number>();
get alertActive(): Observable<number> {
  return this._alertActive.asObservable();
}

setAlertHeight(height: number) {
  this._alertActive.next(height);
}
```

(Note that the `Subject` is a private member but is exposed via a getter as an Observable. In general, subscribers shouldn't have access to the raw Subject unless they'll also be emitting values from it.)

And your child-2 component would subscribe to it like so:

```js
this.service.alertActive.subscribe((height: number) => {
  this.actualHeight -= height;
});
```

You were also on the right track using `ViewChildren` and subscribing to its `changes`, but it might be simpler if you reference the `ElementRef`s rather than the `ViewContainerRef`s. That would look like this:

```js
import { NgbCarousel } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@ViewChildren(NgbCarousel, { read: ElementRef }) carousels: QueryList<ElementRef>;


ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.carousels.changes.subscribe((els: QueryList<ElementRef>) => {
    const height = els.first ? els.first.nativeElement.offsetHeight : 0;
    this.service.setAlertHeight(height);
  });
}
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-listen-for-sibling-component-height-changes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts) showing it working with this approach.